# Access DataModule's event from another Form (delphi design-time)

Tags: delphi, events, design-time, datamodule, object-inspector

I would like to know if there's any way to link a component's event (As `TButton.OnClick`) to a procedure defined in a datamodule (At design-time).
At the moment, I'm doing this at runtime:

```
MyButton.OnClick := MyDataModule.MyOnClickEvent;
```

The goal would be that to get MyDataModule.MyOnClickEvent proposed in the dropdown lists in the Object Inspector Window.
Thanks in advance to all who will share their knowledge :D

**Note1:**
Here's a similar question, but there are no informations about how to accomplishing the same task at design-time:
[Access an event on a DataModule from another Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906853/access-an-event-on-a-datamodule-from-another-form)

**Note2:**
The only way I found consists in define all events on a parent-form, but I was hoping there was a cleaner solution

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know something like this is not possible.

Perhaps with some addons but I doubt it. Why?

Imagine all the cluter that would be returned when you try using something like this on a project with hudreds of forms and thousands of events.

Also how would you deal when you would have multiple events on different forms with same name?

Comment: I agree, a property of a datamodule  with the word 'click' in it doesn't make a lot of sense, since there's nothing to click on at runtime in a datamodule...

Comment: Only events that belong to datamodules which units are in the uses clause would be returned. Exactly as it happens for components, after adding a datamodule's unit to the uses clause, you can link form's components to datamodule's components -> In the dropdown list you can see "MyDataModule.MyComponent".

Answer (score 0):

Define a **published** method in the DataModule to act as the event handler. Its signature must match `TNotifyEvent`.

Make sure the DataModule's unit is in the `interface` `uses` clause of the component's parent Form unit.

Make sure the DataModule is created before the parent Form is created.

Comment: In datamodule class I've added:
published 
procedure OnClickTest(Sender : TObject);.

In form unit I've added
uses
uMyDataModuleUnit.
"OnClickTest" event is not in the dropdown list, did I've done something wrong? Thanks.